# [Python3x]: How to extract two values separately (beautifulsoup)?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the value (coordinates) that I would like to have separately (latitude, longitude).

```
<input id="dokad" value="51.819544, 19.30441" type="hidden">
```

When I do like that:

```
lat_lon = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':'dokad'}).get('value')
```

Result:

```
lat_lon
Out[1012]: '51.186147, 19.199997'
type(lat_lon)
Out[1013]: str
```

How can I extract these two values separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split()` to split string and then `float()` to convert your strings to float:

1. `lat_lon = lat_lon.split(', ')`
2. And then convert your list elements to float by doing this:
   `lat_lon = [float(number) for number in lat_lon]`

now `lat_lon` variable should contain list of floating point values: `[51.186147, 19.199997]`

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt can be something like below to get them separately:

```
content='''
<input id="dokad" value="51.819544, 19.30441" type="hidden">
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")

item = soup.select("#dokad")[0]['value']
lat = item.split(", ")[0]
lon = item.split(", ")[1]

print("Lat: {}\nLong: {}".format(lat,lon))
```

Result:

```
Lat: 51.819544
Long: 19.30441
```